# How to replicate soft deleting functionality?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I created a custom date column in my table, called `finished_at`. I want to replicate the functionality of [soft deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#deleting-models) so that:

1. Rows that have a `NULL` value for the `finished_at` column are not retrieved by default.
2. If I want to retrieve rows with a `NULL` value, I add `withFinished()` to the query (like how soft delete has `withTrashed()`).

How can I do this?

Comment: Laravel sources are open. What prevents you from looking if you cannot come with proper query constrains yourself?

Answer (score 1):

In your model class, use the `SoftDeletes` trait and define the constant to tell laravel the custom soft delete column name.

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    const DELETED_AT = 'finished_at';
    .....
}
```

If you want to use `withFinished` instead of `withTrashed`, you can create your own `CustomSoftDeletes` trait and use the Laravel's `SoftDeletes` trait in it. And create `withFinished` to in turn invoke `withTrashed`. But I don't see a point in why you need to rename that method as it is just an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need change your `Model` like :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes; //<--- use the softdelete traits

    protected $dates = ['finished_at']; //<--- new field to be added in your table

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'test';

}
```